# Getting rid of AwareMem_Kill of Huawei

Tags: huawei, ram

I have a Huawei Mate 9. Somebody thought that using more than half of the memory is evil, so the system kills (yes, actually it does a hard kill, they're even removed from the task switcher etc.) random apps (even low-memory ones, freeing up only a few megs) over and over again (it's sometimes a constant flow of restarting/killing/restarting/killing for a while), when the free memory is around ~ 1.8 GB out of the ~ 4 GB, just to "improve performance" (yes, that's what support guys said).

This line is logged for a few times (and searching for AwareMem_Kill in the internet doesn't bring up results):

```
<datetime> 1024 12427 W AwareLog: AwareMem_Kill: updateGroupList package: move high frequent=<fancy-app>, uid=<uid>
```

Any idea how to disable that "feature" and why Huawei has that weird engineers doing hard kills when 2 GB of RAM are available and not using the Android functionality? Or does the device even not have 4 GB and they're only claiming that and trying to hide the fact? I have no idea ...